# Why in series combination of circuit has same amount of current flow in every conductor?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity

Why in series combination of circuit has same amount of current flow in every conductor? Whereas in parallel combination the amount of voltage is same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can imagine (although roughly due to quantum considerations) that the current through a uniform conductor is equivalent to water flowing in an uniform pipe. Think that there is water flowing through the pipe at some rate. Now, imagine that the pipe is constricted at one of its sections (equivalent to a resistor) .

What happens to the water as it enters the constricted section ? By experience, we say that the water flows at a faster speed. That's because the water has to increase its speed so that it can send the same amount (volume) of water through a smaller area in same time.

In short, the rate of water flowing through every section of the pipe must be equal. If there is a difference in rate between two adjacent sections, then there would be accumulation (or a vaccum) of water at the junction of the two adjacent sections, and the pipe would burst after sometime. However, that is not the case. Also, such an accumulation would result in a higher state of energy at the junction than if the flow rate were to be uniform, which any physical system would not like to be in.

This is the case with electrons too. Here, that 'rate' is current itself, the amount of electrons flowing through the conductor in unit time. If the electrons were to accumulate at the junction of any two different materials in a circuit, it would mean a state of higher potential (and therefore potential energy) since electrons don't like being close to each other in the case where they accumulate. **Therefore the current (rate) is uniform in any circuit no matter what resistors it comes accross in the circuit.**

In a parallel resistance, the amount of electrons to be flown divides between the branches. Therefore, the amount of electrons (and thus the current) in each branch would be less than if the conductor were unbranched. Voltage is to be same across each resistor since both resistors branch from the same potential and  unbranch into the same potential of a different value. Therefore, their 'potential  difference' is same.

Hope it helped!

Take a look at [this](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/watcir.html) link for more analogies between electric current and water flow.

Answer (score 1):

Think of 'electrons flowing through a circuit' as 'marbles flowing through a pipe' where the cross sectional area of the pipe is the same as that of the marble's flat surface when cut in two identical hemispheres. Also the pipe is joined end to end (meaning there is no end). And also the pipe is totally filled with marbles (there is no gap anywhere in the pipe). Now to understand the electron flow, let's consider the marble-pipe analogy.

Suppose if you push one marble so that it moves to it's either side, but then this marble will push other marble which is ahead of it which in turn will push the next marble. This process continues and that is how the marbles flow. Now consider there is no friction between the surface of marble and the surface of the pipe (meaning that the pipe is acting just as a guide to flow). In that case if you push one marble, then the process will continue and the 'circling' of the marbles will never stop (practically not possible though). Now the speed of one marble depends on the speed of the marbles behind it. If yo push harder, the faster the marbles will flow and slower if you push lightly.

Same is the case with the electrons, if there is a resistance anywhere in the circuit then the speed of some electrons will get slower which in turn results in the speed of electrons decreasing in the entire circuit because one electron is pushing the other at a slower rate so it affects the whole circuit.

If you have a circuit which has more than one resistance (let's consider 3) connected in series then that circuit will behave as if you have connected a 'net' resistance instead of 3 (or as many as you wish). And that is the reason why the current is same in all the resistances which are connected in series.